# How can one disable incoming videos on Zoom?

Tags: video-conference, zoom-cloud-meetings

How can one disable incoming videos on Zoom? I use Samsung Galaxy S9 with Android 10.

E.g. in MS Teams one may do it as follows:

[image: Screenshot of Teams settings - Turn off incoming video]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Zoom support-How to stop incoming video-Android](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/4409500570381-Stopping-all-incoming-video-in-a-meeting-or-webinar)

> - Start or join a meeting.
> - Tap the More `...` option in your meeting controls.
> - Tap Meeting Settings.
> - Find and tap the toggle next to the Stop incoming video option.
> - To resume videos, tap the toggle next to Stop incoming video to disable.